How can you capture a screenshot of any window using Python on Wayland?
For context I have a PyQt5 widget with a single button that let's me select a region of the screen to capture. I can use pillow and mss to capture stuff on X11 like so
def take_screenshot(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": y1, "left": x1, "width": x2 - x1, "height": y2 - y1}
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        img = Image.frombytes("RGB", sct_img.size, sct_img.bgra, "raw", "BGRX")
        img.save("screenshot.png")
        print("Screenshot saved as screenshot.png")

But when trying things on Wayland I get an error about XGetImage()
mss.exception.ScreenShotError: XGetImage() failed

I also tried doing things this way
def take_screenshot(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # Ensure x1 < x2 and y1 < y2
    x1, x2 = min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2)
    y1, y2 = min(y1, y2), max(y1, y2)
    
    screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
    screenshot = screen.grabWindow(0, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    screenshot.save("screenshot.png", "png")
    print("Screenshot saved as screenshot.png")

But that just results in a black screen capture, which I understand happens because Wayland has security features that explicitly prevent capturing stuff from 1 window into the next
Is there some Python library I can use? As a final solution I can use gnome-screenshot or some analogue to take screenshots from a subprocess, but I want to keep things as simple as possible

Currently (July 2024) there's not a unique, common and reliable way to capture a screen region on Wayland as there is with X11, as it depends on the compositor and configuration.
Both pillow and Qt have related reported issues that are still unresolved.
Despite being almost 15 years old, there is no common protocol for screen capture on Wayland.
The policy of both projects is to provide an API that should work transparently and consistently on every system, so the situation will probably remain unchanged for quite some time (my prediction is that it won't happen for at least a year, maybe more), until a common interface is finally available for Wayland.
